# How to generate DTM from point cloud data?

Tags: dem, terrain, point-cloud

I have point cloud data obtained from drone. I need to generate DTM out of it. How can I generate and I checked options in ArcGIS and QGIS. I was not able to find any.Could anyone suggest a method to generate the same?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to create a DTM/DSM in both programs. All tools are good, but can be tweaked to give you results based on your precise needs - of which you haven't included any - in your question.

Take a look at these tools, all of which were also discussed on gis.stackexchange, to find the one to best fit your needs

- ArcGIS - [Topo to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/topo-to-raster.htm)
- QGIS (Grass) - [v.surf.rst](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.surf.rst.html)
- QGIS - [Grid Interpolation](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html)